# What is clr.dll on .Net framework and what does it do?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr, profiler

I use profiling tools on VS2012 and see,that clr.dll works a lot of time.
Is it Garbage Collection? What clr.dll can do? Please tell me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Common Language Runtime. It's basically the engine for .NET

Answer (score 23):

clr.dll is the primary binary in the .NET runtime version 4.0 and forward. This dll used to be mscorwks.dll in previous versions of .NET.

Comment: thanks man i was thinking to ask a question about this, and found this post.

Comment: so the .net 2.0 and 3.5 use **mscorwks.dll** and upper one use **clr.dll**?

Comment: Correct. The DLL name changed with version 4.0.